# Cannot get back the total count of friends - Facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am user `PHP facebook API` to get the Facebook's user data. And I am trying to get the total friends.

I am using `Graph API` and it return this:

```
{
  "id": "12312312312312",
  "name": "myName",
  "friends": {
    "data": [
      ],
    "summary": {
         "total_count": 89
    }
 }
```

}

But When I use my code:

```
$profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name, friends');
$profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
print_r($profile);

//It return these to me:
Array ( [name] => Myname [friends] => Array ( ) [id] => 12346677888 )
```

The friend array only return a null value to me.

How can I get back the `total count`?

thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but this may be helpful for someone since I was just looking for this answer by myself. And I found it.

You have to get graph node without asArray to grab total_count.

For example:

```
$getGraphNode = $profileRequest->getGraphNode();
$profile = $getGraphNode->asArray();
```

$profile will act the same, but you will now have graph node without asArray, so you can grab total_count.

```
$total_count = $getGraphNode['friends']->getMetaData()['summary']['total_count'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Facebook v2.0 upgraded you can try like this "user_friends".

[Upgrade Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids)